# YouTube video sound volume radically changes between videos

Tags: windows-10, audio, youtube

If I play a YouTube video at a certain volume, sometimes when the next video plays, the sound gets louder. I know something is wrong because if I adjust the volume (on the taskbar), increasing the volume actually causes the sound to be softer. The issue also appears to happen if I pause the video for a few minutes.

What could be causing this issue? I'm using headphones, the browser is Google Chrome, and the operating system is Windows 10. The issue doesn't seem to happen if I remove the headphones and rely on the built-in speakers, and it also appears to happen less if I use a different browser (tested with Microsoft Edge).

Comment: This will be the preset gain when the video was recorded, youtube doesn't perform any normalisation on uploaded content to set the same audio output gain level. If you watch the same video 10 times over, is the sound level consistent?

Comment: @spikey_richie the issue happens when I play through videos in a playlist ... I can't put the same video into a playlist, so I don't know unfortunately.